# Bootstrap Navbar Search form. Query not routing to correct controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, postgresql, devise

Hello my fellow rails developers,

I have a simple search form in my navbar that runs a search in the :address column of my Users table through the jobs_path (nested resources):

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= simple_form_for(jobs_path, method: :get) do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :address, params[:address], placeholder: " Votre Ville..." %>
      <%= submit_tag 'Rechercher', class:'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </form>
```

here is the routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users

 get 'static_pages/home'

 get 'static_pages/faq'

 get 'static_pages/about'

 get 'static_pages/cgu'

 root   'static_pages#home'

 get    '/faq',    to: 'static_pages#faq'
 get    '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
 get    '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
 get    '/cgu',     to: 'static_pages#cgu'
 get    '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
 get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
 post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
 delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'

 resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
 resources :jobs
 resources :users do
  resources :jobs
 end

 resources 'contacts', only: [:new, :create], path_names: { new: '' }

  if Rails.env.development?
   mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: "/letter_opener"
  end

end
```

Yes, jobs: is there twice as I need to access the Jobs actions for visitors (outside of Devise).
The user model shows:

```
has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy
```

And the Job model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

My Jobs controller shows:

```
def index
@jobs = if params[:address]
  Job.joins(:user).where(users: { address: params[:address].downcase 
}).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
else
   @jobs = Job.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4).order('id DESC')
end
end
```

and Rails routes gives:
[image: Rails routes]

My problem is, that the request gets lost in routes and sometimes goes to the wrong controller. If I'm on the Jobs#index page : http://localhost:3000/jobs
and run a search for a city like "Nantes". The query runs fine:

```
Started GET "/jobs" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-16 10:47:07 +0400
Processing by JobsController#index as HTML
Rendering jobs/index.html.erb within layouts/application
(0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"
Job Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $1 
OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 4], ["OFFSET", 0]]
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 
$1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 
$1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 
$1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
CACHE  (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "jobs"
Rendered jobs/index.html.erb within layouts/application (35.6ms)
Rendered layouts/_header_out.html.erb (1.9ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 96ms (Views: 92.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

If I'm running the query from my root page ie: StaticPagesController, the query is sent to StaticPagesController and NOT to JobsController:

```
Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&address=Nantes&commit=Rechercher" for 127.0.0.1 
at 2017-11-16 12:11:48 +0400
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "address"=>"Nantes", "commit"=>"Rechercher"}
Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered static_pages/_logged_out_home.html.erb (0.8ms)
Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Rendered layouts/_header_out.html.erb (2.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 56.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

How do I make sure the query is always sent to the correct controller, regardless of where I am?

I hope someone has a solution....Thank you in advance

Comment: Please post the server output when searched from the root page.

Comment: Do you know about `rails routes' or 'rake routes' ?

Comment: So no one has an idea? I am really stuck with this one! THANKS

Comment: This is a duplicate question that has an answer
[It can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47385188/search-form-not-routing-to-proper-controller-in-rails-5-1/47432391?noredirect=1#comment81855732_47432391)